# @RenderBody() wont show any views after deploying to webhosting site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, web-hosting

I have uploaded my project my css and pictures work. But it seems like @RenderBody() doesent work at all. I have tried to erase everything at home/index and adding a text just to see it there was something wrong with index but nope. The text doesent show eather..

Any idé?

Comment: Does any ASP.MVC mechanism work? Have you entered address using routing /Home/Index or /sth/Index.cshtml? Are you sure your hosting provider supports ASP.MVC at all?

Comment: Thanks alot! it was the ASP.MVC mechanism! Please dont vote down for no reason.

Comment: I haven't voted down.

Answer (score 0):

The page is rendered without any dynamic content because a web server doesn't support ASP.MVC. Only static HTML content will be visible then, moreover no routing will be available, so you can enter address such as http://addr/view.cshtml but not proper MVC address like http://addr/Controller/Action.

Comment: At first I had a problem with the database so I tried to set the routing to "noDbControllerName"/Index. And then I had forgotten to change it back to Home/Index. That was all!